# Microsoft Enterprise Library Caching Application Block not thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, thread-safety, enterprise-library

I created a super simple console app to test out the Enterprise Library Caching Application Block, and the behavior is baffling. I'm hoping I screwed something that's easy to fix in the setup. I have each item expire after 5 seconds for testing purposes.

Basic setup -- "Every second pick a number between 0 and 2. If the cache doesn't already have it, put it in there -- otherwise just grab it from the cache. Do this inside a LOCK statement to ensure thread safety.

APP.CONFIG:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="cachingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="Cache Manager">
    <cacheManagers>
      <add expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="1" maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="1000"
      numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="10" backingStoreName="Null Storage"
      type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheManager, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      name="Cache Manager" />
    </cacheManagers>
    <backingStores>
      <add encryptionProviderName="" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      name="Null Storage" />
    </backingStores>
  </cachingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Expirations;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static ICacheManager cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager("Cache Manager");
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleep for one second.
                var key = new Random().Next(3).ToString();
                string value;
                lock (cache)
                {
                    if (!cache.Contains(key))
                    {
                        cache.Add(key, key, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null, new SlidingTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
                    }
                    value = (string)cache.GetData(key);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} --> '{1}'", key, value);
                //if (null == value) throw new Exception(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT -- How can I prevent the cache from returning nulls?

```
2 --> '2'
1 --> '1'
2 --> '2'
0 --> '0'
2 --> '2'
0 --> '0'
1 --> ''
0 --> '0'
1 --> '1'
2 --> ''
0 --> '0'
2 --> '2'
0 --> '0'
1 --> ''
2 --> '2'
1 --> '1'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: So in conclusion, The [Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) "performs in a thread-safe manner".

Comment: It seems, Contains() just returns true if item is expired. But GetData() returns null in this case. If change that condition to if ((value = GetData(...)) == null) everything works fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I notice that you seem to be getting `null` back from the cache whenever that item hasn't been accessed during the previous 5 loop iterations (ie, 5 seconds). Could this be related to your 5 second expiry time?

It seems unlikely, but maybe you have a race condition and the items are dropping out of the cache between the `Contains` check and the `GetData` retrieval.

Try this change and see if it makes any difference to the output:

```
while (true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    var key = new Random().Next(3).ToString();
    string value;

    lock (cache)
    {
        value = (string)cache.GetData(key);
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = key;
            cache.Add(key, value, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null,
                new SlidingTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} --> '{1}'", key, value);
}
```

Comment: I understand why people would do this, but honestly you'd figure the cache would be curteous enough not to make you go through this nonsense. Honestly, I just want to do 'GetData' and supply a RefreshAction and be done with it

Answer (score 10):

What you are seeing is that your CacheItem has expired due to the 5 second SlidingTime expiration.

Before returning the cached value, the GetData method performs a check to see if the CacheItem has expired.  If it has expired, the CacheItem is removed from the cache and null is returned.  However, the call to Contains will return true because the CacheItem is in the cache even though it's expiration may have elapsed.  This seems to be by design.  With that in mind, it would be wise not to cache a null value to represent no data since you would not be able to discern an expired CacheItem from an actual cached value of null.

Assuming that you do not cache a null value then Luke's solution should suit you:

```
value = cache.GetData(key) as string;

// If null was returned then it means that there was no item in the cache 
// or that there was an item in the cache but it had expired 
// (and was removed from the cache)
if (value == null)
{
    value = key;
    cache.Add(key, value, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null,
        new SlidingTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
}
```

See [The Definitive Guide To Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://books.google.ca/books?id=eZXOfFiv6A4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA187#v=onepage&q=&f=false) for more information.

Comment: it is, plus a little explanation.  I marked your answer as the accepted answer, Luke.  I also +1'd both.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons that `.Contains` can come back as `true` and `.GetData` can return a `null` is that `.GetData` goes through the whole expiration system (it seems to only return data which isn't expired) and `.Contains` doesn't check to see if it's content is expired.

```
{
    cache.Add("key", "value", CacheItemPriority.Normal, 
              null, new SlidingTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
    Console.WriteLine(cache.Contains("key"));        /// true
    Console.WriteLine(cache.GetData("key") != null); /// false
    Console.WriteLine(cache.Contains("key"));        /// false
}
```

Another problem I had was that I couldn't tell whether the cache contained an entry with null as the value or the cache just didn't contain an entry for key. A workaround that I use is that if `.GetData` comes back with a `null` and `.Contains` is `true`, then a `null` was purposefully stored in the cache and is not expired.

Comment: I think it's possible for the `cache.Contains()` to return true, then have the data in the cache expire, then have `cache.GetData()` return null because the cache item has expired.  The null return value wouldn't mean that a null value was stored in the cache.  Granted, this is an unlikely edge case but I think it's possible.

Comment: @Tuzo Right. If the data expired, the GetData call to it would return null normally. You can only tell if a null was purposefully stored in cache if the data wasn't expired.

Answer (score 1):

Although this might not fix your particular problem, double-checked locking is usually suggested...

```
if (!cache.Contains(key))
{
    lock(mylockobj)
    {
        if (!cache.Contains(key))
        {
             cache.Add(key, key)
        }
    }
}
```

Also possibly look into CacheItemRemovedCallback.

Comment: Double-checked locking is a bad habit, not to recommend since it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

A bit old, however I faced a very similar issue today in that if I retrieve a value from the cache that is due to expire (plus up to 25 extra seconds) I receive a null value. However Microsoft have acknwoledged this situation and suggested a fix [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib%20FAQ&referringTitle=Home), I just have to figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but the issue is that you're using `Contains` then attempting to retrieve the value. In between the time `Contains` and `GetData` were called, the item expired and was removed, so `GetData` returned null.  This is known as a race condition.

The solution is quite simple (without using locks), don't use `Contains`

```
private static void CachingBlockTest()
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        var key = new Random().Next(3).ToString();
        string value = cache.GetData(key) as string;

        if (value == null)
        {
            value = key;
            cache.Add(key, value, CacheItemPriority.Normal, new RefreshAction(),
                new SlidingTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> '{1}'", key, value);
    } 
}
private class RefreshAction : ICacheItemRefreshAction
{
    public void Refresh(string removedKey, object expiredValue, CacheItemRemovedReason removalReason)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1} removed", removedKey, expiredValue);
    }
}
```