# Link multiple DataTables to the same DB table

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, synchronize

I'm writing an application in C# in which two or more users on different computers have a DataTable filled from the same table in a SQLite database shared over a network. I would like the datatable of all users remain synchronized, so that if a user makes a database operation (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE), the DataTable of other users remain updated without having to reload the entire table from the database.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Cache on your Client side.

That's what was proposed here : [How to synchronise/check the data from database to datatable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210148/how-to-synchronise-check-the-data-from-database-to-datatable-in-c)

Instead of the ASP.NET Cache proposed there, you could use the Caching Application Block : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649093.aspx

You can find an example of this in this SO thread : [Microsoft Enterprise Library Caching Application Block not thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302643/microsoft-enterprise-library-caching-application-block-not-thread-safe)

The Cache is responsible to check all the changes each X seconds in the database and once it finds something changed, it's reloaded from the database and you'll have to update it in your application.

You can have a smarter way to do this, still with a Cache.

You create a service on your server which receives all INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE orders, it applies them to the database and then send to all your clients' caches an invalidation message to tell them to update their data.

This implies that your client, when started, subscribes to an invalidation notification service and so gets informed when there are changes.

If you're interested in looking at this, you have a nice tutorial here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51409/Exploring-Caching-Using-Caching-Application-Enterp which will be helpful to fully understand what is a Cache and how this one is working.

Comment: My application should work without a server, which is why I chose SQLite. Is this method working wihout a server?

Comment: Yes, it will work, you won't be able to have the invalidation notification service, but you can still have the Cache on each client which is responsible to update itself !